Chrome Extension - get element right clicked on?
my extension was using the clipboard to send text to the focused element.. well v3 broke it. cant get the clipboard working now so, hoping this may be a different solution.
I would like to capture the element I right click on (text box) and then send test to it
Basically, like how a form auto filler does it, but I want to add text to the box.
back story: i love to enter contests lol. In twitter, you often have to tag people od enter a username etc. So my extension allowed me to just right click and pick "Tag 2 people" from my context menu and it would paste 2 friends twitter @'s in the text/reply by setting the clipboard/pasting
I know you cant grab the dom active element because when you click the context menu, thats the active element.
Its driving me nuts lol
(I have another post about using the clipboard with no reply yet, so i thought maybe someone would have another idea on how to do it)
THANKS
tried using clipboard, could not get it to work
